# Как написать логгер, который сохраняет все логи приложения в Room?

Tags: android, android-room, логирование

У меня есть приложение и нужно сделать так, чтобы все логи записывались непрерывно в Room. Как такое можно реализовать?

**UPDATE**
Возможно ли такое сделать без сторонних библиотек и запустить его лишь в одном месте - классе Application()

Comment: Элементарно, придумайте как выглядит Entity "одна запись лога", напишите DAO для него и сохраняйте.

Answer (score 1):

Ничего сложного тут нет. Пишете свой класс Logger (можно `Object` в `Kotlin` или `Singleton` в `Java`) который принимает на вход какую-то сущность типа:

```
class Log(
    val message: String,
    val tag: String
    // any other parameters
)
```

Создаете DAO для ваших логов и пусть ваш логгер сохраняет все поля в эту БД.

Comment: Для запуска логгера достаточно ли прописать строчку
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d -v threadtime") ?

Comment: Не могу вам подсазать по этому вопросу, я слабо представляю что эта строчка делает. Но запускать вы его можете в onCreate Application. Или сделать ему ленивую инициализацию, чтоб он запускался при первом обращении к нему